# Reeb orbit and open books

Tags: sg.symplectic-geometry, 3-manifolds, contact-geometry

Weinstein conjecture is about existence of a closed orbit of the Reeb vector field on every contact manifold. On the other hand, we know every contact 3-manifold admits a compatible open book, which implies the binding is tangent to the Reeb vector field, doesn't this imply the Weinstein conjecture? since the binding is a closed orbit of the Reeb flow?

Comment: It looks like the question is about the quantifiers (any/some contact form ...): [Weinstein conjecture](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weinstein_conjecture)

Answer (score 1):

Compatible open book only requires the binding to be a transverse link.

In this case the contact form is isotopic to a contact form, where the binding is tangent to the Reeb vector field. But it is not the Reeb vector field of the original contact form.

Comment: @nikita I was wrong to say "contact structure" in the answer. The Weinstein conjecture asks for a closed orbit for each contact form, not each contact structure.